# Workbook property missing from Excel Web Access Webpart

Tags: web-part

When adding an Excel Web Access Webpart to my page, I am unable to supply the Workbook property. It simply doesn't show up in the tool pane.

[image: tool pane]

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Sharepoint.

Reference: [MSDN](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07abbdf3-b88d-49d3-aea6-48b4e684cb78/excel-web-access-webpart-dont-have-woorkbook-property?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious), [MSDN](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/46af7cae-5672-4cbf-82aa-84218e776184/how-do-i-display-workbook-display-section-properties-in-the-excel-web-access-web-part-tool-pane?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Comment: Any advice if that's not something easily facilitated or accomplished by me?